# Is there any viewengine exists for PHP so my asp.net mvc site has PHP as language for my VIEWS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, design-patterns

Now I'm working with asp.net mvc, it's good framework. But, in future, I want to work with php or ruby to develop views for my asp.net MVC site.

I am not sure what this concept is called but I know something exists.

I think, I must generate pages with clear html, javascript and use json for transfer data. What patterns I can use and how implement navigation?

Any other thing exists to do this?

Comment: Okay so do you want your "Views" to be created using PHP or Ruby? Is that correct?

Comment: I want maximum unbounded from C# for quick implement on server-side php or ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in case if you wish to create your VIEWS for asp.net MVC site using PHP code you can opt for PHP View Engine.

It  allows you to write ASP.NET MVC views in the PHP language.

http://phpviewengine.codeplex.com/ is link you can follow.

This way all your ASP.NET code for Controller And Model will be intact and you can create your views in PHP.

I hope this is what you would be looking for.

Another view engine for php is [sharpy](http://sharpy.codeplex.com/) I hope this also could be one for you. On top of that I am not sure anything is there for ruby.

Answer (score 0):

> I want maximum unbounded from C# for quick implement on server-side
>   php or ruby.

Based on this comment, your only option to have server-side code return data in a standard format (like JSON) and rely heavily on client side templating to turn data into HTML.

LinkedIn had a similar problem.  They had three different server side technologies and had a hard time re-using components.  There is a good write-up about their experience [here](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/leaving-jsps-dust-moving-linkedin-dustjs-client-side-templates) and a pretty through comparison of different templating technologies [here](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more).

Answer (score -1):

Consider using Mustache (http://mustache.github.com/) as your view engine. It will allow both PHP, .NET and JS to consume the views and render with server-generated content. Nustache has a library for ASP.NET MVC as well to make the transition easy.

Comment: @JigarPandya Based on the comment about wanting to be unbound from C# on server side, I think this is exactly what he's asking about.